# cygwin basic command trouble

Tags: cygwin

I'm using Cygwin to simulate Linux environment on my Windows 7 machine for learning some basic commands and functions. Right now, I am just practicing moving through directories and different file pathways I've created. I have read that I can move backward (or upward) in my file path by typing `cd . .`, but this is not working. For example, my pwd: `/home/temp/stuff/things`, but when I type in `cd . .` on the next command it reads the same pwd. Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding the `cd . .` command?

Comment: Can you clarify the process you are following a bit? (use of backticks may help for formatting) How are you checking the PWD, for example?

Comment: You should not have a space between the dots in your `cd` command. It should be `cd ..` -- `cd<space><dot><dot>`

Comment: No worries! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Put a space between cd and .., so *cd ..* and not *cd..*. The second one works in dos but not in unix/cygwin.